# How to call a custom web service in SharePoint 2010 protected by Site Minder?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, siteminder

I have a web service deployed in SharePoint 2010 environment protected by SiteMinder.
I need a way to authenticate with the SiteMinder and then be able to call 
 that web service and get some result back from the call.

I am not seeing any useful resource after searching Google.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks